# How to determine if a block is on minority fork from geth console?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs

So right now my current blocknumber is 600,000+ , Is there anyway to check if a particular block number is on the forked chain ?

Answer (score 1):

If/when `geth` is working correctly, you are always on the longest (valid) chain it knows about.